# Load an additional config file aside from cassandra.yaml in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to have Cassandra load an additional config file with other properties, along with the default one? (/etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can change it to use a different file (by setting `-Dcassandra.config=file://your/path`), but only a single file. If you really want though, you can write a custom config loader (like the YamlConfigurationLoader) and set it with: `-Dcassandra.config.loader=your.Loader`.